# Is image slider possible in wordpress post

Tags: custom-post-types, slideshow

I am writing a post in which I've following images line by line which I need to set as a slider.

Theme is generatepress.
[image: images in post]

Will it require coding or a plugin will help.

Looking forward for helpers. Any source is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiair with generatepress, but with almost any theme; if you want to customize the content with functionality that is not in the theme, you will have to use either a plugin or code a child theme.

There are lots of slider plugins out there, so just read their intro's and documentations. I mean...   [click](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+slider+plugins+wordpress)

Look for plugins that can insert sliders with shortcodes, or have other means of inserting sliders into existing pages, so that you can still use generatepress for pages and posts.